# How to keep the UISearchBar's placeholder along with search icon left-aligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I want to keep UISearchBar's placeholder along with search icon left-aligned in all versions of iOS. then,how can I handle with it?

I attempt to append whitespace character to the UISearchBar's placeHolder, It seems to resolve the problem, But I want to know whether exist elegant method to handle this problem.

Comment: Hi, Tricking UISerachbar approach is not the solution

Comment: You can customise search bar like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542549/customize-search-bar/36543336#36543336

Answer (score 1):

Use UItextField and customise the textfield as you desire rather then tricking UISerachbar with whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtSearchBar = [self putsearchIconOnLeft: txtSearchBar];



-(UITextField*)putsearchIconOnLeft:(UITextField*)setTextField
{
    UITextField *txt = setTextField;
    UIView *viewTmp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 10, 10)];

    UIImageView *imgSearch = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    imgSearch.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-search.png"];
    [viewTmp addSubview:imgSearch];

    txt.leftView = viewTmp;
    txt.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    return txt;
}
```