# Can't change colour of UISearchBar clear button image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the colour of the clear button icon for my `UISearchBar` using the following code:

```
let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
if let clearButton = searchField?.value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton {
    clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    clearButton.tintColor = .white
}
```

This doesn't work if called in `viewDidLoad` because the clear button isn't visible. How do I make this work?

Note: This is not related to the tinting of the cancel button or anything else as stated in the comments, just the clear button that looks like an x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the colour of the 'Cancel' button on the UISearchBar in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302760/how-to-change-the-colour-of-the-cancel-button-on-the-uisearchbar-in-swift)

Comment: read the accepted answer and comments below it

Comment: see this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542549/customize-search-bar/36543336#36543336

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542549/customize-search-bar)

Comment: None of these supposed duplicates are related. They're to do with tinting the rest of the search bar, which I have all ready done. Mine question is specific to the clear button, not the cancel button.

Comment: As per what I know, you can't change clear button's color, if you still want to change it, then you can use image of your choice to in place of clear button's actual image.

Comment: @MehulThakkar My code does change the colour of the clear button but only when used in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`

Comment: If you want code for how to update clear button's image, then let me know. I can post the code.

Comment: @Tometoyou: I know that... I have also worked on this, 1-1.5 months ago, and it was not working as expected. Thats why, finally I updated the image of clear button and it worked as I expected it to be.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem on iOS 12.